# Clarity Design Datagrid how to change column width

Tags: css, angular, styles, vmware-clarity

I want to manual set column(head and body) size(width, height).
I tired to set style but not work and find all document not found about this.

DataGrid Component

[image]

DataGrid set width size not work

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the column width:

`<clr-dg-column [style.width.px]=“200”>my column</clr-dg-column>`

This will also set width for all column cells.

To control height and width you can either put the datagrid inside a container with a set height/width.

Comment: Can you have document for all setting style support ?
and 
Can i setting style via Typescript ?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you are asking for here. Is there any way you could make a stackblitz that shows me what you mean with code? https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Answer (score 0):

After i tired use set style on template(html) 
my column

I have other problem when use follow Server Driven(https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/server-driven)

When next pagging each column length adjusted according to data i found overlap column

[Data overlap column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6pMv.jpg)

and when binding long length data i found header separate column incorrect

[header wrong separate column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBUCy.jpg)

My solution i think i have to loop for looking longest length and setting style width and writing logic in to typescript.

Have any solution easy way please suggest me.